# Popup can't show

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have this popup:

```
<dxpc:ASPxPopupControl runat="server" ClientInstanceName="pcMFileBrowser" id="pcMFileBrowser" Modal="false"
HeaderText="Browse M Files" EnableClientSideAPI="True" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" 
PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" CloseAction="None" ShowCloseButton="False" EnableAnimation="False">
<ContentCollection>
<dxpc:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                TEXT!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</dxpc:PopupControlContentControl>
</ContentCollection>
</dxpc:ASPxPopupControl>
```

and this button:

```
<dxe:ASPxButton id="_ShowM" runat="server" Text="Browse M" Visible="false" skinid="WideButton" autopostback="False" ClientSideEvents-Click="function(s, e){pcMFileBrowser.Show();}" causesvalidation="False" enableclientsideapi="True" wrap="False"></dxe:ASPxButton>
```

but When I click on the button it's not show...
I tried with

```
<dxe:ASPxButton id="_ShowM" runat="server" Text="Browse M" Visible="false" skinid="WideButton" autopostback="False" ClientSideEvents-Click="ShowPopup" causesvalidation="False" enableclientsideapi="True" wrap="False"></dxe:ASPxButton>
<script ......> function ShowPopup(s, e){pcMFileBrowser.Show();}</script>
```

but now its always on top...

Answer (score 0):

Change the javascript so return false and not make post back.

```
<script> 
       function ShowPopup()
       {
         pcMFileBrowser.Show();
         return false;
       }
</script>
```

Second change the way you call it as:

```
<dxe:ASPxButton id="_ShowM" ... ClientSideEvents-Click="return ShowPopup();" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not work.. With first when I click - popup isn't show.
With second solution - the button is unavailable.

Comment: @user1278667 I am not giving you two solutions ! Both must be applied.